# Excel countifs criteria neither this nor that

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, countif

Im trying to make a criteria for `COUNTIFS` such that the value of the cell is neither "pass" nor "fail" nor blank. How can I do this? I dont think "<>pass<>fail<>*" works

Since someone wanted this... I dont want to count the same things 3 times over. Thats kind of silly.

Answer (score 2):

Just make three separate conditions:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$10,"<>pass",$A$1:$A$10,"<>fail",$A$1:$A$10,"*")
```

Comment: But then I have to iterate through all the cells three times! This sheet might get VERY big, and this would not be efficient.

Comment: If that is your concern, include it in your post.

Comment: @Dgrin91 :  You don't actually know that it's any less efficient (internally to Excel).  It may not look pretty, but it is the way COUNTIFS works:  3 criteria=3 ranges, even if ranges are repeated.  There are alternate methods for getting your end result (e.g. helper columns), but you only asked how to do it in COUNTIFS.

Comment: @Dgrin91 FYI, this calculates ~instantaneously for >600,000 test records to search through. You only need to worry seriously about inefficiency if you are using thousands of these `COUNTIFS` formulas.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative. It's an array* formula though, and I'll wager it's slower than `COUNTIFS`

```
=SUM(N(IFERROR(MATCH("x"&$A$1:$A$10,{"xpass","xfail","x"},0),0)=0))
```

The "x" kludge is because I couldn't figure out how else to get the "" condition to count properly.

Array* formula: commit with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`, not just `Enter`.